# Merge Two Unallocated Partitions

Tags: partitioning, formatting, merge

I have a HDD with 3 partitions, an Unallocated 232GB, a 450 MB Recovery, and another unallocated 363.74GB.  What I would like to do is merge the two unallocated spaces.  The 232 GB and the 363.73GB for one partition of approximately 585.73GB and the recovery partition which, I expect will change in this process.  However, I seem to be blocked at my attempts so to accomplish this.

I am running Windows 10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad.

Any helpful advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Give us the partition map as-is

Comment: There is no such thing as an "unallocated partition" simply unallocated space. The unallocated word is talking about the fact that the space has not been allocated to be part of a partition.

Answer (score 2):

You can only merge *contiguous* space to a partition.

From what you describe, your free spaces are not located next to each other. You need to move the existing partition to either the beginning or the end, then you can make one partition of the rest.